# How do I submit individual table rows within a form?

Tags: jquery, html, forms, local-storage

I am using localStorage to capture form data offline so it can later be uploaded when an internet connection becomes available. Each set of data is displayed as a new row within a table. My table is wrapped in a form and the td elements have hidden input tags with values equal to their contents as below. This is created dynamically with jQuery.

```
<tr>
  <td><input type="hidden" name="FirstName" id="FirstName" value="Ollie">Ollie</td>
  <td><input type="hidden" name="Surname" id="Surname" value="Clark">Clark</td>
  ...and so on
</tr>
```

I have successfully managed to submit the form to the database with only a single row present. However, when I have multiple rows things get complicated, since all the td elements share the same ID. Is there any way I can make the form submit each row individually once the Submit button is clicked? Possibly through some kind of loop? Any answers appreciated, I have Googled this and can't seem to find anything useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery .each() function to repeat the same action on all elements captured by a selector. So you could do something like:

```
$(td).each(function(index, element) { 
    // do submitting stuff
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you're looking for, but this may help too. 
You can name all your input the same, eg "inputField"

```
<tr>
  <td><input type="hidden" name="inputOne" id="FirstName" value="Ollie">Ollie</td>
  <td><input type="hidden" name="inputTwo" id="Surname" value="Clark">Clark</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input type="hidden" name="inputOne" id="FirstName" value="Ollie">Ollie</td>
  <td><input type="hidden" name="inputTwo" id="Surname" value="Clark">Clark</td>
</tr>
```

So when you form is submitted, do the following in your servlet, you should have an array of all the inputs, in the order it's displayed in your html page.

```
String[] inputOneArray = request.getParameterValues("inputOne");
String[] inputTwoArray = request.getParameterValues("inputOne");
```